# Como importar um arquivo xls para o Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou iniciando meus estudos no Python e gostaria de importar uma base de dados que esta em `.xls` para o Python. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

OBS: Versão Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada no pacote [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). Algum tempo atrás [uma outra usuária do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14489/mary-tortugo) fez uma série de perguntas sobre esse assunto, se você der uma olhada nelas você encontrará alguns exemplos de código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai precisar de bibliotecas externas como o [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) para fazer isso, dê uma olhada em [www.python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Em todo caso eu sugiro salvar o arquivo como csv a partir do excel e usar o modulo csv do python, vai lhe poupar muito tempo e dor de cabeca

Exemplo que copiei na cara de pau do site [oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Veja mais exemplos [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo real utilizando o xlrd:

```
import xlrd

def xls_parser(arquivo):
    tabela = xlrd.open_workbook(arquivo).sheet_by_index(0)
    qtd_linhas = tabela.nrows
    linhas = []
    for i in range(1, qtd_linhas):
        linhas.append(
            {
                'linha': i + 1,
                'valor_coluna_1': tabela.row(i)[0].value,
                'valor_coluna_2': tabela.row(i)[1].value,
            }
        )
    return linhas
```

No exemplo acima, a função recebe o caminho do arquivo e, posiciona o cursor no começo do arquivo. A partir disso busca o total de linhas do arquivo.

Tendo o total de linhas, faz um `for` utilizando o `range` e transfere essas informações para uma lista de dicionários, facilitando a manipulação.

O script também armazena nos dicionários a linha em que foi retirado o conteúdo do XLS. Mas pode tirar aquela parte caso essa informação não seja relevante.